# Finding parameterization of simple vector valued function - verification on right path

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

A question asks me:

Find the parameterization of the following lines:

1. $3x_{1} + 4x_{2} = 6$
2. the line with slope $\frac{1}{3}$ that passes through $(-1,2)$

Attempts:

to parameterize these equations what I need to do is find a direction vector from which I can then express these equations as functions of a single variable $t$

**1)**  If I rewrite the equation as $x_{2} = \frac{6}{4} - \frac{3x_{1}}{4}$ and I choose any two different values for $x_{1}$ such as letting $x_{1} = 0$ and then $x_{1} = 1$, I will get a set of points: $\textbf{x}_{\textbf{0}} =(0,\frac{6}{4})$ and $\textbf{x}_{\textbf{1}} = (1,\frac{3}{4})$ respectively. Using these points I can now get a direction vector, $\textbf{v} = \textbf{x}_{\textbf{1}} - \textbf{x}_{\textbf{0}} = (1, \frac{-3}{4})$. Having this direction vector I can now choose either of the original points I created to write the parameterization of the line. Choosing $\textbf{x}_{\textbf{0}}$ as my point I arrive at an equation:

$$\textbf{f}(t) = \textbf{x}_{\textbf{0}} + t\textbf{v} = (0, \frac{6}{4} + t(1,\frac{-3}{4}), \ t \in\mathbb{R}$$.

**2)** Rewriting the expression into a point intercept form I first have

$$y - 2 = \frac{1}{3}(x + 1) \\ y = \frac{1}{3}x + \frac{7}{3}$$

Again I have to get a direction vector $\textbf{v}$. So letting $x = 2$, I get $y = 3$. From which I can now get a direction vector: $\textbf{v} = (2,3) - (-1,2) = (3,1)$. As such I can now parameterize the line as:

$$\textbf{f}(t) = (-1,2) + t(3,1)$$

My only question pertaining to these problems is if my thought process is the right one to apply? Mainly I'm concerned about how I obtained the direction vectors and if what I did was what you are supposed to do in these situations.